# How to use gcov with Cmake

Tags: c++, cmake, gcov

I'm having difficulties following this guide (that I've seen recommended on another post) on the matter https://github.com/bilke/cmake-modules/blob/master/CodeCoverage.cmake

First:

> Copy this file into your cmake modules path.

How do I know what my cmake module path is?

> Use the function SETUP_TARGET_FOR_COVERAGE to create a custom make
>   target

What does it mean exactly? How do I do that? Especifically, what do I have to type and where?

I am forced to compile the application with cmake, otherwise I would do it with gcc.

Comment: CMake modules path is `/usr/share/cmake/Modules` or similar. You may deduce it from the list of installed files with cmake package: there are a lot of `.cmake` modules in that directory. As for other questions, read `USAGE` section in the file you refers. In short, target created with `SETUP_TARGET_FOR_COVERAGE` runs some *workload* and collects coverage produced by the executable in that directory. If  you just want to compile your executable with gcov support, step 3 (setting compiler flags) alone is sufficient.

Answer (score 7):

You set the cmake module path by calling 
    `set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH <path>)`

The cmake module path setting tells cmake where to look for cmake modules like those that are included by the `include` macro.

For example, the steps I took to use CodeCoverage.cmake are:

1. Copy CodeCoverage.cmake into my source folder at 'scripts/cmake'.
2. Add the following to my CMakeLists.txt:

   ```
   set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/scripts/cmake)

   if (CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE STREQUAL "Coverage")
       include(CodeCoverage)
       setup_target_for_coverage(${PROJECT_NAME}_coverage ${TEST_TARGET} coverage)

       SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-g -O0 -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage")
       SET(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "-g -O0 -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage")
   endif() #CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE STREQUAL "Coverage"
   ```
3. Run `cmake` with `-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Coverage`
4. Run `make`
5. Run `make <coverage_target>`

Note that:

- `${TEST_TARGET}` is a variable I set with the name of my unit testing target that I create earlier in the script.
- `<coverage_target>` is whatever string that is generated by `${PROJECT_NAME}_coverage`.
- You don't have to wrap the coverage creation with the `if` like I did.
- Since I'm using AppleClang, I had to fix the CodeCoverage.cmake script to allow it. The way it is written now allows gcc and clang 3.0.0 or newer only.

Comment: I could not find a `setup_target_for_coverage` function in CodeCoverage.cmake.  What worked for me: `setup_target_for_coverage_gcovr_xml(${PROJECT_NAME}_coverage NAME coverage)` (and then make && make coverage)

Comment: Jan 10: the github repo you link changed the function name setup_target_for_code_coverage to 
append_coverage_compiler_flags_to_target

Answer (score 2):

### gcov with zero lines of CMake

As an alternative to using a CMake module for gcov integration, it is possible to use do it without modifying the build system at all. You only need about 5 lines of shell. This is a nice approach for projects that are not too large or complicated.

By the book, one must feed a list of source file names (excluding headers) to gcov. This is based on various naming and directory conventions: gcov assumes that the source files have a name like `foo.c` or `foo.cpp` and that the corresponding object file is called `foo.o` and is in the same directory as the source file. But CMake, by default, names them like `foo.cpp.o`. gcov strips the extension of the given source file name, and then adds the `.gcno` and `.gcda` suffixes. We can exploit these facts by feeding gcov, instead of source files, the *.gcda* files. As it turns out, gcov will look for everything in the right places in that case.

#### How-to

1. Turn on coverage data in the compiler and linker flags by adding the `--coverage` flag to `CMAKE_C_FLAGS` and/or `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS`. This makes the compiler generate .gcno files at build time, and it makes executables dump .gcda files on exit.
2. Make a script for the [run test / generate report / clean coverage data] loop. Here's a barebones Bash example:

   ```bash
   # Ensure we are in the build directory and that coverage was enabled in the compiler
   grep -q -- --coverage CMakeCache.txt || exit 1

   # Clean up old runtime data
   find . -name '*.gcda' -exec rm {} \;

   # Run test command (specified as script arguments)
   # This can be anything that runs program(s) built by the project 
   "${@}"

   # Generate reports (.gcov files). All .gcda files in the build directory are passed as gcov args.
   find . -name '*.gcda' | xargs gcov
   ```

#### Pros of this approach

- Same script can be reused, without having to perform CMake integration on each project of interest
- No complicated CMake code
- Flexibility to easily change the test command. A CMake-integrated clean/run/report loop likely has a hard-coded command to run all tests, which is often less useful (and slower) than running a single test.

#### Cons

- Full path information is lost. The name of each .gcov file includes only the basename (`foo.gcov`), whereas normally it would encode the full path like `src#foo#foo.gcov`. This could result in name collisions in report files.
- Lack of integration of dependency information into the build system means you may accidentally use old .gcno files upon forgetting to rebuild (if `--coverage` was turned on and later turned off).